# Vue inline-template with v-for - not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am attempting to learn Vue and trying to implement a simple test, utilizing inline templates and `v-for` loops.

When I load the below page, I receive the following error and no content is rendered to the screen.

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "posts" is not defined on the instance
>   but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data
>   properties in the data option.

I am a beginner with Vue, but any help would be most appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vue Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3.4/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="vue-app" class="container">
            <post-list inline-template v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.id">
                <div class="post">
                    <h1>{{ post.subject }}</h1>
                </div>
            </post-list>
        </div>

        <script>
            Vue.component('post-list', {
                data: function() {
                    return {
                        posts: [
                            { id: 0, subject: 'The first post subject' },
                            { id: 1, subject: 'The second post subject' }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            });

            new Vue({
                el: '#vue-app'
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `v-for` needs to be *inside* the template. [inline-template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates) means that everything *inside* the element is the template.

> the component will use its **inner content** as its template

`v-for` is not inside, so it is trying to iterate the `post-list` component looking for `posts` on the root Vue and it isn't there.

Also, iterating the root element would result in more than one root (which isn't allowed), so I wrapped the `v-for` in a `div`.

```js
Vue.component('post-list', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      posts: [{
          id: 0,
          subject: 'The first post subject'
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          subject: 'The second post subject'
        }
      ]
    }
  },

});

new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-app" class="container">
  <post-list inline-template>
    <div>
      <div class="post" v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="post.id">
        <h1>{{ post.subject }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </post-list>
</div>
```